Options to calling Autolaunched flow from apex batch job
I am trying to call autolaunched flow from Apex batch job but getting CPU time limit exceeded as i have few get records inside the loop. Is there any way to create or pass map to Salesforce flow so as to avoid get records inside loop. It is hitting CPU time limit even with batch size of 50.

You could directly pass in collections objects as a list then loop over it within the flow.
For this answer I'm using Account object as an example.
Variable to create on flow:

Apex Code:
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 2]; // Replace with what you need

Map<String, Object> inputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
inputMap.put('accounts', accounts);

Flow.Interview flowInter = Flow.Interview.createInterview('<Auto_Launched_Flow_API_Name>', inputMap);
flowInter.start();

